# Creating a list box in PowerShell and performing an action with the selection

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a PowerShell script which creates a list box listing all the App-V packages within a folder. The folder contents are read in by running script to lists all the App-V packages in within a folder.

Question how do I then script the selected item to then install the App-V package using the below commands

Add-AppvClientPackage | Publish-AppvClientPackage -global.

I also need it run Enable-appv as administrator before running the above commands.

Is the above even possible, sorry I am very new to PowerShell Scripting and would appreciate any help, tips or suggestions.

Below is the code I have so far

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Select an App-V packag to install"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"

DialogResult property to OK.
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$objForm.AcceptButton = $OKButton

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"

$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel

$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objForm.CancelButton = $CancelButton

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Select an App-V packag to install:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$objListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objListBox.Height = 80

Get-Content Z:\App-V_Package\appv.txt | ForEach-Object {[void] $objListBox.Items.Add($_)}

$objForm.Controls.Add($objListBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$result = $objForm.ShowDialog()

If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{   
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
Break
}

Enable-appv 

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK -and $objListBox.SelectedIndex -ge 0)
{
    $selection = $objListBox.SelectedItem
    $selection | Add-AppvClientPackage | Publish-AppvClientPackage -global
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with App-V stuff but have you considered using [Out-GridView -PassThru](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-5.1) for displaying your list and making a selection? Maybe you could pipe your list of packages into it?

I wrote a [blog post](https://robin1996.github.io/powershell/2017/12/11/PowerShell-git-branch-GridView.html) the other day about using it to select git branches.

Comment: Thanks Robin, appreciate your reply. Will look into it.